# UITableviewCell not taking complete width in CarPlay

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have created a custom tableViewCell with a single label. When I run the app in the CarPlay simulator the width of the cell is not completely taken. Some space is left on the left and right side. I have tried setting the constraints to the container that is holding the tableView, the tableView, the customTableViewCell but it is not working. Following is the image [image].

Answer (score 0):

You should set Constraints of UILabel with **Leading space to superview** and **Trailing space to superview** with constant **0**.

See the Picture for more Detail.

[image]

Comment: can you please share your code, So i can reach exact problem. @srb1991